# Is the pressure * volume a constant in a balloon?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure

I'm having a question about balloons. I want to know that is the P*V of a balloon always a constant or no?

Comment: What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

The ideal gas law states $PV=nRT$. If you change $n$ (the amount of air) or $T$ (the temperature), you will change the product $PV$. So the answer is "no".

Comment: Oh, Yes!!! You're right